# PDO with CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: codeigniter, pdo

Can you provide me good tutorial about CodeIgniter and PDO?  Is it good to use CodeIgniter framework with PDO?  What are the pros and cons using PDO with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have some of tutorials for PDO + CodeIgniter

> [CodeIgniter with PDO](http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/03/codeigniter-with-pdo)
>
> [Using PDO in CodeIgniter](https://tutsplus.com/forums/topic/using-pdo-in-codeigniter/)
>
> [Using PDO in CodeIgniter](http://christopherickes.com/web-app-development/using-pdo-in-codeigniter/)
>
> [EllisLab Forum: How to implement PDO in CodeIgniter](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-implement-PDO-in-codeigniter-1438197.S.199985238)
>
> [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)